# Where does Virtualbox store Literally ALL of its Files & Packages?

Tags: virtualbox

So I'm thinking of installing Virtualbox on my Ubuntu machine but I'm not completely sure if I actually should. One thing that I am uneasy about is the fact that I don't know where all the files are stored. I am simply installing virtualbox with apt (but not directly downloading the .deb from the website), like this:

> sudo apt install virtualbox

I'm not that crazy about what packages are coming with virtualbox, but I'm more concerned about every single file virtualbox adds to my filesystem so I know what to remove and how to remove it if I want to completely remove virtualbox.

Basically, I would like to know all the locations where virtualbox stores every single one of its files.

*I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS*

Comment: If you want to remove Virtualbox, you will use apt. And apt DOES know where all the files are located. But, for the fun of it, answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Look up the package** (and each dependency) in https://packages.ubuntu.com ...

[image: package.ubuntu.com page for virtualbox]

... and **Scroll to the bottom** of the page...

[image: bottom of the page]

...and **click on the link** for "list of files"

Answer (score 3):

You can get this info from the Properties menu in `synaptic`...but only for installed packages.

I have `virtualbox-6.1` installed, not `virtualbox`, but here is the information for that (in a pastebin, it is over the 30,000 character limit for an answer :(

https://pastebin.com/9rJAJuGd

FWIW, virtualbox is a wonderful tool, I use it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The VirtualBox *Program Files* (windows term) will be located in your root (`/`) filesystem. Complete file list for deb-package from official repository is [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/amd64/virtualbox/filelist) (about [110 Mb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/virtualbox)).

The VMs will be stored by default inside your home folder in folders like `~/VirtualBox VMs` (you can [change this location](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#vboxconfigdata-summary-locations) from preferences if you have problems with free space). Some settings will be stored at `~/.config/VirtualBox` .